# Is "Er ist gehend" or "Er ist am gehen" proper German?

Tags: tense

Is "Er ist gehend" possible in german? As in "Right now he is going".

I realize that adding another word, as in "Er ist gehend nass geworden", makes more sense, but still "Er ist gehend" doesn't sound completely wrong in my ears, although clearly it's not really in use.

Similarly, people use "Er ist am gehen" to say "he's just leaving". But a) is this proper German? And b) isn't that ambiguous, as it could also mean "he's walking at the moment"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. That's wrong.

The German language does not contain such a feature as English does. Hence, you use the simple present. From context it's clear if the action happens right now or not. However, to avoid any misunderstandings, you can add words like *gerade* (English *right now*) for clarification.

Thus, "He is going" is translated to "Er geht (gerade)".

Based on the other answer, I must disagree in one point. "Er ist am gehen" often means that you're about to leave, but it's incorrect to say that it never means "He's walking". But again, context clarifies and you will be able to distinguish the meaning.

Comment: I agree about "am Gehen"... context matters here. I'd like to add, that grammatically "Er ist gehend" is correct, it just doesn't mean much.

Comment: @Emanuel Well, assuming *gehend* would be a participle adjective, the sentence is indeed grammatically correct. However, in this context it's rather a literal translation of the English progressive aspect which is ungrammatical in German.

Comment: @Emanuel Nur, dass du mich nicht falsch verstehst. Ich bin in dem Punkt etwas pingelig, damit potentielle zukünftige Leser(=LanguageLearners) nicht den Eindruck gewinnen, dass "Er ist gehend" nur zufällig bedeutungslos ist, da die Grammatik ja ansonsten richtig ist (was dein Kommentar suggeriert).

Comment: This is only nitpicking but- you only know that it is a literal translation because you know English. From a strictly German point of view it is a participle adjective  https://www.google.de/search?q=es+ist+*d&rlz=1C1DVCJ_enDE430DE443&oq=es+ist+*d&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.10603j0j4&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=%22er+ist+nervend%22

Comment: @Em1... aber genauso ist es... manchmal heißt es was und manchmal nicht (die d-form am Ende meine ich)

Comment: @Emanuel Fair enough. Aber in deinem Eingangskommentar fehlte die Erklärung. Und ich bezweifle, dass jeder LanguageLearner auf Anhieb den Unterschied zw. *gehend* und *nervend* erkennt. (Das gleiche gilt auch für's Englische: "He is going" vs "He is irritating". Grammatikalisch zwei paar Schuhe, optisch dasselbe. Und im Deutschen ist eines von beiden halt falsch. Wer von der Grammatik wenig Ahnung hat, könnte hier Probleme bei der Übersetzung bekommen.

Comment: @Em1... Das ist doch genau mein Punkt... es gibt in Deutsch keinen Unterschied! Es sind eben genau nicht 2 paar Schuhe. Allein, das Adjektiv "gehend" macht keinen Sinn.

Comment: @Emanuel Und da wiederspreche ich. "Schreiend", "sagend", "fahrend" usw. ergeben auch keinen Sinn. Man kann nicht jedes Partizip 1 verwenden. Worin erkennst du (als LL) den Unterschied?

Comment: @Em1... das ist egal. Wenn ich meinen Computer programmiere, dann ist das Semantik, oder Wortschatz aber nicht Grammatik. Das Pattern: "Subjekt ist x-end" ist in unserem Kopf als möglich abgespeichert.

Comment: @Emanuel Ich glaube, wir drehen uns im Kreis. Aber ich denke, wir verstehen beide die Argumente des anderen, deswegen bin ich dafür, das jetzt so stehen zu lassen. So, ich bin dann jetzt mal spazierend.

Answer (score 5):

*Er ist am Gehen* can be heard in colloquial German, but generally in German there's no difference between the simple form and the continuous form. That's why it is so hard for us to grasp the concept :-)

Jokingly people call this the "Rheinische Verlaufsform", because it is very often heard in the Rheinland area. You can hear gems like

> Weißt du, was du bist? Du bist deinen Schal am verlieren!
>   Do you know what you are? You are losing your scarf!

But please note that this is actually dialect!

*Er is am Gehen* in the sense of *he's just leaving* is more common, even though *Er ist gerade dabei zu gehen* is "better" German.

---

I'd like to add that there *are* situations when *er ist XYZ* are used, but not as present continuous, but as participle. Examples are:

> Er ist sehend (meaning that a person is not blind)
>   <strike>Er stellt sich schlafend (meaning that he pretends to be sleeping)</strike>

Comment: While "er ist sehend" is grammatically correct, I don't think anyone would say it. Instead people would say "er kann sehen" to indicate that he is not blind. "Er stellt sich schlafend" is different because it doesn't contain "ist".

Comment: I agree with you on *er stellt sich schlafend*, but I've heard *er ist sehend* sometimes (even though I must admit that *er kann sehen* is the better way to say it).

Comment: I would assume spontanously without context that "er ist sehend" refers to some kind of clairvoyance. It's extremely strange to use that instead of "er kann sehen".

Answer (score 4):

In German you wouldn't use the participle in such a way. If you want to explicitly express that somebody is doing something right now, you could use the word "gerade" as in

> Er liest gerade.

The phrase "Er is am gehen" is indeed used in spoken German, but it hardly ever means that "he's walking at the moment". In almost all cases it means "he is just leaving". In written German it would be better to phrase it like

> Er ist im Begriff zu gehen.

Comment: It's not a participle, it's the present continuous.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar... it is the participle 1 form, used to produce the present continuous. You need to distinguish between form and function

Comment: @Emanuel Interestingly, if you search the Internet you find both, statements that say the present participle is used for the progressive tense and statements that claim the present participle just happens to be equal to the verb-form in the progressive aspect. Note that you also distinguish between gerund and participle, although there's no difference in spelling. I think you'll find valid arguments for both thesis.

Comment: @Em1... luckily we're not discussing English grammar :). I was referring to the German participle because this is how I understood the sentence. Beside, there are HUGE issues in grammar teaching when it comes to form vs. function (subjunctive vs. conditional, just to name an example) so I have no doubt I can find sources for any claim. Also, English grammar is a mess and they are at each others throats as to whether or not they have a predicate nominative. Also there I can find treatments for both parties

Comment: Well, you may argue that `going` is the participle of `to go` and that even though `subject + is + ing-form of verb` are generally taught as the `present continuous` it is hard to distinguish from the participle form. Still, in this case it is pretty clear that a translation for the present continuous is asked for, so I'd stop the discussion here.

Comment: Or would you translate *He's just leaving* as *Er ist nur verlassend* without crying a little?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar: You cannot translate "Er ist gekommen" mit "He is come" either. Word-by-word translations rarely work, and therefore are not a valid way to determine the type of word or the grammatical form.

Comment: @celtschk I think you're missing my point. I say that `subject + is + ing-form` is the so called present continuous. Emanuel corrected me by saying that *going* is the participle, which is correct if you regard only the word itself. However, I'm just saying that you need to regard the entire grammatical construct, not just part of it. If you did that, you'd translated *He's just leaving* as *Er ist gerade verlassend*, which you don't because you know that *He's just leaving* is present continuous.

Comment: You claimed that his claim in the comment that it is a participle is wrong. But that claim clearly is directed at the single word, not at the complete construct. Especially given that he was speaking about the *German* word, where there is no such thing as a continuous form, at least not in the official language.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar... well, if I insert that in the answer for the word "participle" I'll get a statement that claims: German HAS a present continuous but it doesn't use it that way. Matt L says that German doesn't use the participle the way English does and that statement is correct. If you want to work "present continuous" into that that would be extra, not instead.